# Modify this whitelist function, so that it returns an object with specific key value fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to write a whitelist utility function that can be used across several different post and patch requests. Right now, I'm trying to make it work for just one scenario.  A user makes a post request, the request comes back with an object that has several fields, we only want the user to be able to create or edit certain fields in the request.  For this example, the two fields are key1 and invoiceDate.

I have an array I define ahead of time, here it is called acceptableLine1.  This utility method should be able to compare the request body with the acceptableFields array and determine determine that this is a vLineValue, make a copy of the request body, the new body will only have the keys key1 and invoiceDate and it should populate the new objects keys with the values from the request sent by the user.

I'm having trouble with the check and returning the new object with the values.  Right now, the result object makes a copy of all the keys from the request object and all the values from the request object, it should only make a copy of the fields key1 and invoiceDate, and populate it with values from the request.

Sorry for the lengthy explanation, hopefully its clear, if any clarification needs to be made, i'll be happy to explain further.

```
const acceptableLine1 = ['invoiceDate', 'key1']
// body that comes from a bill line post request
let vLineValue = {
  id: 19,
  invoiceDate: '2000-01-25',
  key1: 'abc',
}
export default async (
  body,
  acceptableFieldsOne,
  acceptableFieldsTwo,
  acceptableFieldsThree,
  // acceptable fields are arrays of acceptable fields for post or patch requests to bills, bill-lines, dist-lines
) => {
  // start off with taking the body input and making a copy of it
  const whiteListBody = body;

  // after making a copy of the body, check each of the arrays, see if the body has keys that match any of the array strings
  // get an array of the keys from the body
  const whiteListObjectKeys = Object.keys(whiteListBody);

  // get an array of the whiteList objects values
  const whiteListObjectValues = Object.values(whiteListBody);

  // compare whiteListObjectKeys array with each of the acceptableFields arrays
  // if the arrays match, return a new object with the keys that match and their original values

// result should only have the keys 'key1' and 'invoiceDate' with the values 'abc', '2000-01-25'
  result = Object.fromEntries(
    whiteListObjectKeys.map((_, i) => [
      whiteListObjectKeys[i],
      whiteListObjectValues[i],
    ])
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return the needed entries by using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of an array. Turn the `body` object into an array with `[key, value]` pairs by using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), filter that array and turn the entries back into an object.

Also, you don't really need to create a copy of `body` but if you do use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to make an actual copy.

I've created `...acceptableFields` [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to accept an unlimited amount of `acceptableFields` arrays. These arrays will be combined into a single array with [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) which the filter will loop through.

```
const acceptableFieldsVoucherLine = ['invoiceDate', 'description']
// body that comes from a voucher line post request
let VoucherLine = {
  id: 12,
  invoiceDate: '2020-02-27',
  description: 'abc',
  voucherId: '18',
  createdBy: 'some value',
  orgServiceDate: null,
  paymentDate: null,
  processingDate: null,
  updatedBy: null,
  createdAt: 'some value',
  updatedAt: 'some value',
  amountCents: 0,
  federalAmountCents: 0,
  nonFederalAmountCents: 0,
  archivedAt: null,
  lineNumber: 7
}
export default async (body, ...acceptableFields) => {

  // Start off with taking the body input and making a copy of it.  
  const whiteListBody = Object.assign({}, body);

  // Convert object to array with entries: [key, value] pairs.
  const whiteListEntries = Object.entries(whiteListBody);

  // Combine all arrays into a single array.
  const acceptableFieldsList = acceptableFields.flat();

  // Function for checking if the key matches an acceptable field.
  const whiteListHasEntry = ([key, value]) => acceptableFieldsList.some(field => field === key);

  // Filter the entries with the whiteListHasEntry function.
  const filteredWhiteListBody = whiteListEntries.filter(whiteListHasEntry);

  // Turn the result back into an object.
  const result = Object.fromEntries(filteredWhiteListBody);

}
```

Comment: This is close, but there is an issue, when you declare the whiteListHasEntry constant, based on the [key, value] thats entered there, it should be able to switch between different 'acceptableFields' arrays.  Currently, it is only accepting 'acceptableFieldsVoucherLine'. For example, if a key in the array was 'description' then use acceptableFieldsVoucherLine, if a key was something else, then use that other array with the .some() method

Comment: I've modified my answer. It now accepts an indefinite amount of `acceptableField` arrays that the `whiteListHasEntry` will loop through.